# Extract images from live video feed of ipcamera

Tags: python, opencv

I want to extract images every 5 minutes from a webcam live video feed using opencv. I have the below code to extract from a video. But don't know how to do it for a live video stream from an ipcamera

Below code is used to get an image every 5 seconds from a valid video

```
import cv2

videoFile = "folder-path"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)
success, image = cap.read() 
success = True
count = 0

while success:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,(count*1000)
    success, image = cap.read()
    cv2.imwrite("file path/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)
    count = count + 5
```

Comment: can you just take a screenshot every 5 min?

Comment: Do you know how to open a webcam in OpenCV?

Comment: instead of using `cv2.VideoCapture('path/to/video/file')` use `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `cv2.VideoCapture()` with the index of the camera you care about. If you have only one camera, `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` will do the trick. If you have multiple, you will want to increment the index until you are accessing the correct camera.

This code will capture a frame from camera 0 every 5 minutes:

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)   # start a connection to the camera
ret, frame = camera.read()     # read a frame
cv2.waitKey(300000)            # wait 5 minutes
```